# How do I get the Word Text Effect property through the add-in API?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, office-js-helpers

I am trying to write a Word add-in (Javascript) leveraging the Word add-in API and I have hit a roadblock.

I cannot seem to find the property for the Text Effect of a letter or a word, it does not seem to be in the FONT

Can anyone help?

These are the steps I am trying to follow:

In Word 2016, you would select the text you want the effect on, 
then select the "A" icon (blue I think, next to the Highlighter),
then apply an effect - like OUTLINE

Andy

Comment: To what kind of "text effect" are you referring? Can you tell us the commands used in the Word UI to create it? And/or include a screen shot? (Use the [edit] link below the question to add information to it, directly.)

Comment: Sure.  In Word 2016, you would select the text you want the effect on, then select the "A" icon (blue I think, next to the Highlighter, then apply an effect - like OUTLINE